# How to add custom texture with shapefactory shape (cube) in my code?

Tags: textures, arcore, sceneform

I created a white cube in my project as shown below. now I want to add texture to it. How can I do that?

```
MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(this, new Color(android.graphics.Color.WHITE))
  .thenAccept(
    material -> {
      modelRenderable =
        ShapeFactory.makeCube(new Vector3(0.8f, 0.15f, 0.8f), 
                              new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), 
                              material);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a texture material and set it to you created shape like this:

```
    //sampler for the texture
    val sampler = Texture.Sampler.builder()
            .setWrapMode(Texture.Sampler.WrapMode.REPEAT)
            .build()

    Texture.builder()
            .setSampler(sampler)
            .setSource(this, R.drawable.your_drawable_texture)
            .build()
            .thenCompose { texture ->
                MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithTexture(this, texture)
            }
            .thenAccept { material ->
                ShapeFactory.makeCube(vector, vector, material)
            }
```